# Best value AMD CPU for under $70

Tags: processor

This CPU is for a gaming system under a tight budget. However, there is no need for an integrated GPU. In my current state, I am looking for the best AMD CPU available to buy. It can be any socket, as a new motherboard is needed anyway. 
So my question is, what is the best value AMD chip under $70 for performance and value.

Answer (score 4):

The best available CPU at ~70$ U.S. is the AMD Athlon X4 860K. It is an FM2+ socket Kaveri chip with for compute cores. It is clocked at 3.7 Gigahertz stock, though generally has very good overclocking potential, if interested, and also happens to be the CPU that powers my system.

Pretty much any Intel CPU beats it out in single core performance at stock, but when overclocked, it approaches i3 performance per core and has an extra 2 cores to work with.

The AMD FX-6300 is also another chip you might want to look into. It has 6 cores, each slightly inferior to the X4 860K's. However, it costs $90 and is on a dying CPU socket, the AM3+, which will be totally replaced by Zen later this year.

If you want to wait for the new Zen AMD CPUs to come out (AM4 socket), that is a good idea too, as they are supposed to actually compete with Intel i5 and i7 processors.

Comment: I thought FM2+ will be replaced by AM4 as well.

Comment: It seems like AMD will continue using FM2+ for some APU's, but move to AM4 for the nicer processors, like the FX series

Comment: [Not what I heard](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3020184/computers/amd-zen-based-cpus-and-apus-will-unify-around-socket-am4.html). Zen supposedly unifies AMD's 3 sockets. according to every news source I've seen.

Comment: I don't know much about the zen architecture, other than it is supposedly faster and more power efficient than FM2+ or AM3+. Feel free to edit the answer the answer at your discretion to add or change whatever information you would like to about Zen.

Comment: The answer is correct, but there's a lot of discussion here that needs correction: first, the 860K is a *mediocre* overclocker; it is unusual for anyone to get it going faster than 500mhz over its boost clock. Second, while FM2+ is indeed going to be replaced by AM4, just as sockets AM1 and AM3 will presumably be, it is *highly* unlikely that anything on that socket would fit the budget and so is not worth discussing. No further processors are planned for any of the existing AMD sockets.